# how to add Active Admin form input :html {multiple => ""}?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

ActiveAdmin form:

my problem: I can not get a form with multiple choice files(

I tried:

```
      ActiveAdmin.register Foto do: 
       form :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
         f.inputs "Upload" do
          f.input :foto, :as => :file
         end
         f.actions
       end
      end
```

this does not work, then I made a simple html page with two forms:

```
    <!DOCTYPE doctype html>
    <html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
      <!--**not** work multiple choice files-->
      <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input id="image" name="image" type="file"/>
      </form>

      <!--**great** work multiple choice files-->
      <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="#" method="post">
        <input id="image" name="image" type="file" multiple=""/>
      </form>

     </body>
    </html>
```

Question: how to add a property to multiple input field ?

I tried:

```
     f.input :foto, :as => :file, :html => {:multiple => ""}
     f.input :foto, :as => :file, :html => {:multiple => ""}
     f.input :foto, :as => :file, :html => {"multiple" => "multiple"}
     f.input :foto, :as => :file, :html => {:multiple => :multiple}
```

this does not work

help me, please.

Comment: what do you mean by does not work ? throws some error ? not selecting multiple file ?

Comment: Try this `f.input :foto, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true }` . If it works, I can post it as answer. I have not tested it

Comment: No need to use     ':html => { :multipart => true }' , just use 'form do |f|' , use 'f.input :foto, :as => :file' and check your model that the photo is saved as foto not 'photo' because you have spelling error.

Comment: f.input :foto, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true } - it is works, thanks! Where did you hear about input_html?

Comment: My model is:  class Foto < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :service
  has_attached_file :image
end.   ':html => { :multipart => true }' it is not work!

Comment: @deni5n I don't remember from where exactly, maybe from a doc. But I have used it sometimes so I remember it. Posting my comment as answer, feel free to mark it as a answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```
f.input :foto, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true }
```